# Remove taxonomy menu without removing the metabox?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm creating a custom taxonomy for a CPT and I need to remove the ability to create new terms for this taxonomy. I would like to know if there is a way to remove from admin menu (`show_ui => false`?) but keep the metabox.

I've seen some solutions hooking to the `admin_menu` action and removing manually but I would like to know if there is a way to tell Wordpress when I am [registering this taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) to not put a menu for it and keep the default metabox.

Just to illustrate what I want:

```
+----------+----------------------------+
|  show_ui | meta_box_cb                |
+----------+----------------------------+
| true     | false                      | #=> show menu but remove metabox
| false    | false                      | #=> remove everything
| false    | true (or something truthly)| #=> this is what I want
+----------+----------------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the code you used to register both the CPT and custom taxonomy types.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer based on my testing locally is to change the value from true to false in this line of code which is included when you register taxonomy support for custom post types.

```
'show_ui' => false,
```

Here's the full code i used:

```
add_action( 'init', 'executive_type_taxonomy' );
function executive_type_taxonomy() {

register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-type', 'portfolio',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'          => _x( 'Types', 'taxonomy general name', 'executive' ),
            'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Portfolio Type', 'executive' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Portfolio Type', 'executive' ),
        ),
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-type', 'with_front' => false ),
        'show_ui'             => false,
        'show_tagcloud'       => false,
    )
);

}
```

You could also remove the admin menu based on user roles and capabilities.